# How are configurable options rendering on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

i need to add `data-imagesrc="imgurl"` inside `<option>` tag. It should look something like

```
<option value="16" price="0" data-label="grey" data-imagesrc="imgurl">Grey</option>
```

And when i see the rendered part of configurable options (`app/design/frontend/<mypackage>/<mytheme>/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`)

```
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <?php
    $_rendered = false;
    foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
        $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
        if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
            $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
            $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
            echo $_renderer->toHtml();
            $_rendered = true;
            break;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if (!$_rendered):
    ?>
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                </select>
          </div>
    </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

From where are those options being rendered ? and how can i add `data-imagesrc` inside option tag of configurable combobox ?

I'm trying to achieve like shown on the image below, and i am doing with a jquery plugin.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you those options are rendered in `Prototype` so you will have to connect it with jQuery.
File location:
`js/varien/configurable.js`
I would suggest you to take a close look at `fillSelect` function inside of it.
All the information is gathered inside `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig` function.
Good luck!